# How can I validate exposed filter from View?

Tags: views

I have build View which work for search exactly content by number filed "ICO".
How can I validate exposed filter form for only number and regular expression which enable only eight digit number?

Can you any help me with some example code for build it?

Comment: In the exposed filter operation you can choose regex. You don't have that option?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a custom submit handler to the form like so:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_validation';

function my_custom_validation() {
  // Add the logic that you want in here
}
```

Then use [`form_set_error()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) to indicate if the value is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'events_month_filter_check_month_year';
```

My Requirement was to add a year drop down and I need validate if month and year was given in search. I've added month and year exposed filter in the view. Then I've altered year field from `form_alter` hook like below because I was not getting granular years.

User has to select both month and year when doing a search. If month or year is ignored I should validate and throw the error. this validation worked for me.

```
function events_month_filter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

      if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' 
          && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-civi-events-page' )
      {
          $dropdown_array = array('All' => t('-Year'));
                $dropdown_array[date('Y')] = date('Y');
                $dropdown_array[date('Y') + 1] = date('Y') + 1;

          // Alter form
          $form['start_date_2'] = array(     
             '#type' => 'select',
             '#default_value' => '1',        
             '#options' => $dropdown_array,
          );
          $form['#validate'][] = 'events_month_filter_check_month_year';

       }//endif

     }
```

then validated using `$form['#validate'][] = 'events_month_filter_check_month_year';`

```
    function events_month_filter_check_month_year(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        //dsm('validate function');
            //dsm($form_state);
        $start_date_month = $form_state['values']['start_date_1'];
            if($start_date_month == 'All')
            {
                 $start_date_month = '';
            }

        $start_date_year = $form_state['values']['start_date_2'];
            if($start_date_year == 'All' || $start_date_year == 1 )
            {
                 $start_date_year = '';
            }

            if(!empty($start_date_month)){
                if(empty($start_date_year)){
                    form_set_error('start_date_2', t('Please choose a year.'));
                }

            }
            if(!empty($start_date_year)){
                if(empty($start_date_month)){
                    form_set_error('start_date_1', t('Please choose a month.'));
                }
            }
 }
```

Hope it helps someone in future.